# Any way to inject at beginning of each function in a nested object?

Tags: javascript, function, method-modifier

I have a shared object named *myModule* contains many common-used functions:

```
myModule
  alert: {showAlert: ƒ}
  upload: ƒ (e)
  uuid: {createUuid: ƒ}
  __proto__: Object
```

1. Function maybe child or great-grandchild of *myModule*
2. These functions maybe loaded separately by multiple calls into a page

Now *myModule* maybe used in different script block in one page.

```
<script>
// loaded uuid, alert to myModule
</script>
<div> ... </div>
<script>
  myModule.alert.showAlert(s);
</script>
<div> ... </div>
<script>
// loaded upload to my Module
</script>
<div> ... </div>
<script>
  myModule.upload(f);
</script>
```

Now I wanna put logging at the beginning of each function of *myModule*. *myModule* is owned by my team(in different packages), I do want a way to do it with minimal change to these functions for there're so many functions. Is AOP the good choice? Or any way to make it simple?

Comment: How do you feel about wrapping all functions in myModule with a logger function:
1. `showAlert = () => alert("hi there!")`
2. `wrapper = (fn) => { console.log("log something here..."); fn() }`
3. `wrapper(showAlert)` -> export this from `myModule`

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher I decided to apply [nested Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to myModule to wrap getter.

Comment: Regarding the former `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.